# What is the correct syntax of a method that deletes part of a list and returns true if succesful?

Tags: java, list, methods

I m trying to create a method that searches the content of a `list` called `authors` looking for the element (the author's name) given as arg, and then deletes the specific field. If successful it returns true. But it won't work for some reason. I believe the error lies in the `authors.remove(authorName);` because the `main` class will not erase anything when given the order `Book.removeAuthorByName("White");`.

```
public boolean removeAuthorByName(String authorName){
    boolean val = authors.contains(authorName);
    for (int i = 0; i <= numAuthors; i++){
        if(val = true){
            authors.remove(authorName);
            authors.trimToSize();
        }
    }
    return val;
}

public int listSize(){
    return authors.size();
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of that loop?

Comment: To read and compare the contents of the list

Comment: in your removeAuthorByName function, try to simply return :
        return authors.remove(authorName);

Comment: You might want `==` instead of `=`. Comparison vs. Assignment. In fact, to check for true you can just use `if (val)` or for false `if (!val)`.

Comment: I think @OliverCharlesworth is suggesting that you don't need the loop since `remove` will (if `val` is true){i.e., if `authors` does contain `authorName`) remove that item.

Comment: Oh yeah I still fall for the "=" and "==" thing :S Btw does it matter if authorName is part of an object in the authors list? Would it work if it was 'a' or "abc" for example?

Answer (score 1):

Little more concise and better will be

```
public boolean removeAuthorByName(String authorName){

     int index = authors.indexOf(authorName);
     if(index > -1){
         authors.remove(index);
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: the remove method : 
Removes the first occurrence of the specified object from this List.
Parameters
object
the object to remove.
Returns
true if this List was modified by this operation, false otherwise.
Throws
UnsupportedOperationException
if removing from this List is not supported.

Comment: Still it wont delete the second name which is "White". And the size remains the same :(

Comment: @HappyCane try using a `while` instead of `if` and then test to see if the list was modified outside of the loop. This should remove all occurrences.

Comment: Now that I know the correct syntax I ll check for errors in the other classes. Just a clarification: "the first occurrence of the specified object" means the whole object, right? (so if it s made of 3 strings, all three should match with the given argument)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check whether your list supports the remove(Object) method; it does because otherwise you would have received an UnsupportedOperationException.

You can simply have to call authors.remove(name); the method will return true if the passed name was found and deleted successfully - see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the while loop check using if clause. Also check case sensitivity

```
if(list.contains(authorname)){

    list.remove(authorname);

    return true;
 }
 else
 {
    return false;
 }
```